# React Native push from right or left transition

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to translate both screens at the same time using React Native transitioner? The resulting effect should be something like the following [link](https://marvelapp.com/632hi0h/screen/30168693) but without any overlapping.

I'm also using [this link](https://www.trustedhousesitters.com/engineering/code/react-native-navigation-custom-scene-screen-transitions-and-interpolations/) as a reference for custom transitions, but currently I can only cover the previous screen from the left or right, rather than pushing both screens to the right. Thanks in advance!